# How to write buffer to file without the commas? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, buffer

In Node.js, I am reading a file and splitting it to smaller chunks. Each chunk is stored in its own file. This works perfectly well.

I want to read these files and rebuild the file from the chunks of data. I am able to do it, but I have a little problem I don't know how to solve.

When writing the file built from file chunks, I have comas between all chunks. I would like to know how I can write the file without these comas.

Current code:

```
var resFromChunk = [];

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    resFromChunk.push(fs.readFileSync('./chunks/fileChunk' + i));
}

fs.writeFileSync("refile", resFromChunk);
```

Expected output:

```
this is my file!
```

Current output:

```
t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,m,y, ,f,i,l,e,!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to join and convert a buffer to a string:

> fs.writeFileSync("refile", Buffer.concat(resFromChunk).toString());

If `resFromChunk` is an array of strings you can just join with a blank delimiter:

> fs.writeFileSync("refile", resFromChunk.join(''));

Answer (score 1):

For buffer:

```
var resFromChunk = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    resFromChunk.push(fs.readFileSync('./chunks/fileChunk' + i, 'buffer'));
}

fs.writeFileSync("refile", Buffer.concat(resFromChunk));
```

For string:

```
var resFromChunk = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    resFromChunk.push(fs.readFileSync('./chunks/fileChunk' + i, 'utf8'));
}

fs.writeFileSync("refile", resFromChunk.join(''));
```